# CSS button state weirdness - held click state?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got the hover, active, and focus states covered, but when I click on my button and hold, I get another color (dark blue) that I can't seem to override. Is there some extra button state I don't know about?

https://jsbin.com/kutavovora/edit?html,css,output

```css
.btn-primary {
  background: #f00;
  
  &:hover, &:focus, &:active, &.active {
    background: #0f0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Click and Hold</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because you are using Bootstrap, and it have defined the following styles:

```
.btn-primary.active.focus, .btn-primary.active:focus, .btn-primary.active:hover, .btn-primary.focus:active, .btn-primary:active:focus, .btn-primary:active:hover, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #204D74;
    border-color: #122B40;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to override those styles, you only need to use a more specific selector (`.btn.btn-primary` instead `.btn-primary` only), like:

```
.btn.btn-primary {
  background: #f00;

  &:hover, &:focus, &:active, &.active {
    background: #0f0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok.. meaning what, exactly?

Comment: See my edit to override Bootstrap styles in your example ;)

Answer (score 1):

your problem is because you are using bootstrap, which has **active** state styled here:

```css
.btn-primary.active, .btn-primary:active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  background-color: #286090;
  border-color: #204d74;
  color: #fff;
}
```

so instead of you having this:

```css
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

just change to this:

```css
.btn.btn-primary:hover, .btn.btn-primary:focus, .btn.btn-primary:active, .btn.btn-primary.active {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

here is a snippet:

```css
.btn-primary {
  background: #f00;
}
.btn.btn-primary:hover,
.btn.btn-primary:focus,
.btn.btn-primary:active,
.btn.btn-primary.active {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Click and Hold</a>
</body>
```

Comment: That didn't work. Whether I use `background-color` or `background`, makes no difference.